# Why does TypeScript think my number|undefined Record<> property is undefined within a falsy check?

Tags: typescript

I don't get why this code raises `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.` Why `obj[prop]` check is not enough and what is the proper way of writing this logic?

```js
function test<T extends string>(obj: Record<T, number | undefined>, prop: T) {
  if (obj[prop]) obj[prop]--;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typescript can't handle the generics that well which is described in [ms/TS#33014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33014). Example:

```
function f<T extends 'a' | 'b'>(x: T) {
  if (x === 'a') {
    x; //  T extends "a" | "b"
  }
}
```

The easiest solution would be to store `obj[prop]` in a separate variable and if that value exists then assign a new value to `obj[prop]`:

```
function test<T extends string>(obj: Record<T, number | undefined>, prop: T) {
  let value = obj[prop];

  if (value) {
    obj[prop] = value - 1;
  }
}
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.0.4#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygHgCqJQD1TABM1EMAnGMAcwD4AKOAIwCsAuRAJRQjguI4ANIjAgAtsxQVEAH0ThiKYNRTE6IgA4U4mztgCUiAN4AoRIgA2KKIgBuAQ0sgUiALyIWrANrbdAXQBuU3NEGGBEBkdnFCMzCwsvXx1Nf3d7JxdEAFpEAEZgiwBfUxKgA)